# How to call initWithCoder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nscoder

I have `UIViewController` and `UIView` subclass (lets say `ViewSubClass`). I am using story board. In `mainStoryBoard.storyBord` , I put one `UIView` and set custom class `ViewSubClass`. Now I do not want to create instance of `ViewSubClass` in `UIViewController` like `ViewSubClass *subClassInstance = [[ViewSubClass alloc] init]`. Without creating any instance of `ViewSubClass` in `ViewController`, i want to call `initWithCoder` method. When I run my application , `initWithCoder` method of `ViewSubClass` should be called. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just set your view as ViewSubClass from storyboard interface builder. And initWithCoder will call when app lunch and you access this view...

Comment: but it is not calling initWithCoder method...

Comment: Can you post your screen shot of interface builder

Comment: And you code for `initWithCoder:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below code in your view class .m file

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
```

And Add file name in view Class as below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Actually i have created library...ViewSubClass is file of our library.and I am using it into single View class application...Is there any chance if i use library then it can not call initWithCoder method?

Comment: It should call each time if you follow same steps as above either View file in lib or seperate

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, I've seen `initWithCoder:` not called even though I have the subclass view set up in Interface Builder as shown in the accepted answer.

Blowing away XCode's and the Simulator's caches solves the problem for me.

`Command + Shift + k` is usually good enough for XCode.

Choose "Reset Content and Settings" for the iOS Simulator:

[image: iOS Simulator]